# Run repo with python 2 instead of python 3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, repo

I have just installed repo on my machine.

When I run `repo` to check whether repo is installed properly, there's a warning:

```sh
$ repo
warning: Python 3 support is currently experimental. YMMV.
Please use Python 2.6 - 2.7 instead.
error: repo is not installed.  Use "repo init" to install it here.
```

I added the installation path of repo and python to the user environment.
[image]

Please tell me how to use python 2.7 when I need to run repo. Meanwhile, there are some tools that need to run with python 3.6 also.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `repo --version` as a code block?

Comment: It looks that you have have a Python 3.6 installation. You should install a Python 2.7 (they can easily co-exist on the same machine). Then you tweak the environment variables (or the PATH) for repo to use the Python 2.7 version. Only a comment because I do not know `repo`.

Comment: Python 2.7 is past end of life.  I wouldn't waste a lot of time on it.  If you can't find a version of repo that works with a modern Python, it might be time to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of repo (that is, the 2.x series) support Python 3 just fine, and in fact, do not support Python 2 at all, according to the documentation.  It looks like you're using an older version that wants Python 2, so you should upgrade to a newer version.

Since Python 2.7 is now end of life, it's not a good idea to use it for anything anymore since it receives no security updates.